# Kendo UI tags input

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I need a simple input to enter tags. MultiSelect is not allowing me to type an ad-hoc input. It seems to only allow selection of items already available in the dropdown.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/tag-mode

I tried [AutoComplete](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index). It allows a comma separated input but doesn't have the CSS of tags with close icon for each tag.

The control in [this page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/programming/addremoveclientside/defaultcs.aspx) is what I need. But its for ASP.net AJAX. I couldn't find a similar example for jQuery

Why is such a common scenario so frustrating to implement in Kendo UI ??

Comment: What you mean with *"doesn't have the CSS of tags with close icon for each tag"* ?

Comment: Please check the link in "this page" above. Type something and press tab. see how the word you typed has a background and a 'X' that you can click to remove the item ? Thats the behavior i am looking for.

Comment: The *'MULTIPLE' TAG MODE* example of the multiselect link you've posted seems pretty close of *this page* link, doesn't it ?

Comment: Try entering something that doesn't exist in the dropdown.

Comment: Now I see what you mean.

Comment: since I also searched for such an input on kendo: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/multiselect-as-tagbox here is an MultiSelect to behave as a TagBox

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a sample dojo based on some code I have done to achieve something similar:

http://dojo.telerik.com/orePO

There is a lot going off here. But essentially this will load your existing "tag" list and if the value entered is not found then it will prompt the user to add it to the collection.

The important piece here is this bit:

```
 function addTag(widgetId, value) {
        var widget = $('#' + widgetId).getKendoMultiSelect();
        var dataSource = widget.dataSource;
        var item = { ProductID: 0, ProductName: value };
        dataSource.add(item);
        widget.value(widget.value().concat([item.Value]));

        dataSource.one("requestEnd", function(args) {
                    if (args.type !== "create") {
                        return;
                    }

                    var newValue = args.response[0].ProductID;

                    dataSource.one("sync", function() {
                        widget.value(widget.value().concat([newValue]));
                    });
                });

                dataSource.sync();



        var values = widget.dataItems();

        updateTagList(values);


        return;

    }
```

This function is called from the `NoDataTemplate` template that is defined here:

```
   <script id="noDataTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        <div>
            No data found. Do you want to add new item - '#: instance.input.val() #' ?
        </div>
        <br />
        <button class="k-button" onclick="addTag('#: instance.element[0].id #', '#: instance.input.val() #')">Add new item</button>
    </script>
```

So when the user types something that isn't found it will prompt the user to add the item to the collection.

I have then added some script to show the tags underneath in a list (just so you can see them being added. So I won't go into that here.)

I have also configured the control to hide all the tags under one `tag` element so that multiselect doesn't grow unexpectedly. This can be changed via the `tagMode` option for the multiselect.

Please note that this option has only been present since 2016 Q3 (from memory)

If you need anything else explaining/ expanding on please let me know.

Also see this demo for this feature: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/addnewitem

Comment: With all this complexity, i'd rather just use select2. I've already seen addnewitem - it's not the kind of UX I wanted. MultiSelect assumes user adds a new item only occasionally and drop down is what he/she will use most of the time. This is opposite to tags where most of the time user will enter something that wasn't entered before (atleast in my usecase). This makes the above solution very unsuitable. It's a shame that Telerik doesn't have something so frequently asked for in their package. I am seriously reconsidering purchase. Lucky i ran into this limitation just few hours into my trial.

Comment: To be fair to Telerik on this occasion I think this is a very "specific" requirement, they have given you the features to achieve your task from a functional perspective but it's not the UX you want. There is nothing stopping you from providing a solution with the tools they have provided to deliver your expected UX experience as the framework can be extended. You could always alter this example to just add the item when the user presses `enter` or the widget loses focus etc.

Comment: please also note the majority of the code I provided is actually used to show the tags underneath the control.

Comment: It's not specific at all ! just googling "jquery tags input" gives a bunch of plugins. Any blog post would have a tags input, including stack overflow when you post a question. I've used a few of those as well. That's why when I started to try out Kendo UI, I just assumed a basic requirement like that would exist. This has been a problem with all control libraries. As long as you stick to features they are shipping, you are good. ask for anything else, You will end up doing brain surgery. Also, I need to have the tags input inside grid as inline edit. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: BTW, This has been a requirement that people have been asking for a while. For some reason, Telerik didn't take this on a priority. Now they are potentially losing a customer. If i get a problem like this just hours after I started testing, how many will I encounter down the line ? Can't believe i actually fought for Kendo with my team. </rant>

Answer (score 1):

Kendo has an example of implementing this feature by modifying the multiselect control.  See here:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/multiselect-as-tagbox